# Copying the first half of an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

There is an `ArrayList<Integer> al`, and I want to copy the first half of its elements into another `ArrayList<Integer> firstHalf`. (If al has an odd number of elements, `firstHalf` should have one more element.) However, the following code throws an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`, and says `Index: 0, Size: 0`, though I'm not sure how that would be a problem, since the indices of ArrayLists start at 0. Also, I am aware of `.arraycopy`, but I would like to do it this way, with for-loops.

```
 int x = al.size()/2 + (al.size()%2) - 1;
 for(int i = 0; i < x; i++){
    firstHalf.set(i, al.get(i));
 }
```

Comment: Consider using `subList`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Point to note: `subList()` returns a "view" of the original list, not a copy. So you'd need something like`firstHalf = new ArrayList(al.subList(0, newSize));`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use `add` instead of `set`:

```
int x = al.size()/2 + (al.size()%2) - 1;
for(int i = 0; i < x; i++){
    firstHalf.add(al.get(i));
 }
```

It would be better to use [List#subList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList%28int,%20int%29)

Comment: Ah, thank you, I forgot about that. I was wondering, however, why `.set` doesn't work?

Comment: @howAnAngel_Dies_ To use `set` your list must not be empty. If you do `firstHalf.set(0, something)` and your list is empty, then the element at index `0` doesn't exist, so it can't be set

Comment: @howAnAngel_Dies_ ["**Replaces** the element at the specified position in this list with the specified element."](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#set(int,%20E)) Brought to you by the Committee For Reading Javadoc To You.

Answer (score 10):

[`List#subList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList%28int,%20int%29) is *exactly* suited for this purpose.

```
int chunkSize = al.size() % 2 == 0 ? al.size() / 2 : (al.size() / 2) + 1;
List<Integer> firstHalf = al.subList(0, chunkSize);
```

There are two cases to consider:

- **Even**:  If the size is even, then n / 2 is the correct size to chunk by.
- **Odd**:  If the size is odd, then you need to add 1 to the result for the odd-length list to have the middle value.

Comment: Are you sure about that last sentence? The convention when giving "from" and "to" indices is that the "to" index is **exclusive**. (More importantly, the Javadoc says it's exclusive.)

Comment: Good catch.  Not quite sure what I was thinking there.  Adding 1 to the end of that value should rectify that.

Comment: Now you broke it for lists with an even number of elements. Spoiler: `((al.size() + 1) / 2) - 1`, if you *have* to be clever with modular arithmetics instead of just adding an `if`.

Comment: Caught me again.  Hopefully that's fixed it.

Comment: And what if I wanted an ArrayList<Integer>? I tried casting it, but it says `java.util.RandomAcessSubList cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList` (sorry, I am a novice in this area!).

Comment: @howAnAngel_Dies_ See my comment under the question. Just use `new ArrayList(al.sublist(…));` to make a copy.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach:

```
List<Integer> firstHalf = al.subList(0, al.size()/2 + (al.size()%2) - 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Integer> firstHalf = al.subList(0, (int) al.size() / 2 + 1);
```

Is easier convert the al.size() / 2 to integer than doing "%2".

You add 1 to firstHalf to be bigger than the second half.